# Does msmtp client need sendmail and/or other services installed and running for it to work?

Tags: email, msmtp

Baby steps needed for setting up `msmtp` on a Debian-based Docker container.

I am trying to setup msmtp with system-wide configuration using `/etc/msmtprc`. Do I need to setup other services for msmtp to work?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? Shouldn't a `.dpkg` know its dependencies anyway and pull them in?

Comment: @Robert - it turned out I needed an MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) - I have Postfix installed on the host.